# CodeIgniter—Best Controller Naming Protocol?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been working with CodeIgniter and I'm wondering if the way I'm setting up my controllers is not correct.

I'm trying to incorporate an admin section of my site using the [method 2 found on Phil Sturgeon's blog](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/07/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter).

If I also needed a controller to handle products and users in my front-end, could I name them products.php and users.php or would they cause conflicts?

Thank you for your help!

[image: File Structure]

Comment: @RPM, looks like a simple [finder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_(software)) window to me.

Comment: @RPM Yeah, I just used a finder window to demonstrate the file structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use same `controller` name for both side (backend and frontend) within two different folders, i.e.

```
admin/users.php 
front/users.php
```

But you can also use a `prefix` for readability or to avoid confusions, like

```
admin/adm_users.php // read as admin users.php
front/frn_users.php // read as frontend users.php
```

Comment: how does this affect urls, because mysite.com/index.php/frn_users/ looks a bit silly?